# php select last 5 or 6 numbers with/without space

Tags: php, regex, string-matching

My data looks like:

```
John 123 45
Doe 67890
Elly Clarkson 111 22
Chris Man Wu 44455
some92 thing91103
make1too 12120
make1too45100
```

How can I get last 5 or 6 digits with or without a space between?

Results should be:

```
123 45
67890
111 22
44455
91103
12120
45100
```

Comment: What is "your data"? An Array of strings? Mysql rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data="John 123 45
Doe 67890
Elly Clarkson 111 22
Chris Man Wu 44455
some92 thing91103
make1too 12120
make1too45100";

preg_match_all('/[a-z ]*([0-9 ]{5,6})/i', $data, $result);
$result = $result[1];

print_r( $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('|(?=.{5,6}$)\d+[ ]?\d+$|m', $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Check this **[demo](http://ideone.com/TOvV6C)**.

Comment: I think OP didn't want 6 digits if a space isn't found, but the question is too vague...

Comment: @PauloFreitas - Hard to say. If yes, then additional prefix `(?!\d{6}$)` would fix that...